# Find the probability of pulling three cards of the same suit from a "defective" deck

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Consider this scenario: you are using a defective deck of cards. This deck still has $52$ cards total, though an error at the factory has made it that instead of $13$ of each suit, there are $11$ clubs, $15$ hearts, $8$ diamonds, and $18$ spades. You randomly draw $3$ cards from this defective deck. What is the probability that they are all of different suits?

My attempt: I adapted this from the problem of finding the probability of drawing $3$ cards of the same suit from a standard deck, which I know the solution is:

$\frac{{4 \choose 3} \cdot13\cdot13\cdot13}{{52 \choose 3}}$

How do I adapt this for the situation I have presented? From what I understand, the above formula works because for any combination of $3$ suits that you pick, you know that there are $13$ cards in that suit. But for this problem, we don't have this information.

Comment: The numerator will be the sum of four terms (rather than $\binom{4}{3}=4$ times a common term $13^3$), each of which corresponds to a set of three suits.

Comment: Per the comment of @angryavian, with respect to the numerator, in a normal deck, you have that $S,H,D,C$ are each equal to $(13)$.  So the normal computation of $$4 \times \left[\binom{13}{1}\right]^3$$ actually represents $$\left[\binom{S}{1} \times \binom{H}{1} \times \binom{D}{1}\right] + \left[\binom{S}{1} \times \binom{H}{1} \times \binom{C}{1}\right] + \left[\binom{S}{1} \times \binom{D}{1} \times \binom{C}{1}\right] +\left[ \binom{H}{1} \times \binom{D}{1} \times \binom{C}{1}\right].$$

Comment: Would it be $(abc)/3!+(abd)/3!+(acd)/3!+(bcd)/3!$ in the numerator and ${52\choose 3}$ in the denominator ?  
(Where a,b,c,d are the number of cards)

Comment: why are you dividing the numerator by $3!$?

Comment: @user2661923 so would the numerator simply be $(18 \cdot 15 \cdot 8)+(18\cdot15\cdot11)+(18\cdot8\cdot11) + (15\cdot8\cdot11)$?

Comment: @jemdo yes, that's right.